# Alloc and init buffer and play DTMF

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, dtmf

I want to allocate a memory buffer and initialize it with data of a mathematical equation in order to gain a pure DTMF tone. I am using the AudioQueueServices library to allocate and fill the buffer. I used a formula of 2 sine waves and 2 different frequencies. However, neither a sound nor a tone is not played.

It may be important to mention that the function of AudioPlayer: initWithData:error:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really given enough information to diagnose your problem.  The only obvious question to ask is whether you have setup your audio session?

A good sample to use as a reference is [Dave Dribin's A440 sample](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2010/05/02/ipad_dev_camp_slides/) from iPadDevCamp Chicago.  It shows how to play a simple 440 hz tone using both AudioQueueServices and Audio Unit graphs.  Hopefully that will let you see where your issue is.